# What makes for "good style" in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style

I had asked this question on Stackoverflow, and before it got booed off, I received the helpful suggestion from Péter Török that this might be a better place to post it.

I've been programming in Java for a few years. I've often discussed design decisions with colleagues on the basis of what constitutes 'good style'. Indeed, there are a number of StackOverflow questions/answers that discuss a design on the basis of whether something is 'good style'.

But what makes 'good style'? Like many things, I know it when I see it... but I wanted to have better idea than just my conscience saying that this design doesn't feel right.

What are the things you think about in order to produce good, well designed code?

(I acknowledge that this is somewhat subjective, as what is 'good style' will depend on the task at hand). (Also, I should add that I'm not interested in team styles - e.g. "we use indents of 2 spaces rather than 4"..., and I'm not interested in the Java code conventions.)

Edit: thanks for all the good answers/comments so far. I'm especially keen for answers that would help codify those things that make a programmer's conscience (and possibly stomach) wrench?

Comment: Among many other things listed here, I would definitely make sure to simply state that computers can compile code in just about any way you write it, but ultimately, code needs to be *human readable*.  Comment like crazy!  A good test I like to use: could a person read *only* my comments to learn what the code does, what it's inputs and outputs should be, and the algorithm(s) used to do it?

Comment: @brian, make your code explain  _how_.  Leave actual comments to explain _why_.  In other words, do not comment like crazy (in the general case)

Comment: Brian: That technique is definitely not considered good practice.  Common good practice is to aim to make your code as self-documenting as possible (with clear variable names and function cohesion), with comments to explain the "why" and not the "how".  Comments that explain every little detail are generally considered distracting and often dangerous, since people are less likely to maintain the comments than the code.

Comment: Clarifying: You said, "I'm not interesting in the Java code conventions." but this is because you know them, not because they're unimportant, right?   It's very important to follow the standard coding conventions (classes begin with upper, variables begin with lower, use CamelCase, etc.).

Comment: @Brian: I would almost flag that comment except that it's offered in the spirit of good advice. Unfortunately it's not good at all. To quote a national speaker, "Even your IDE knows that comments aren't useful. It greys them out for you."

Comment: @Ryan, not Eclipse which colours them green.  Perhaps moldy?

Comment: @Scott - exactly. A lot of the answers so far, whilst very appropriate answers to my question, have been some what 'bread and butter'. I'm trying to elicit ideas as to how to improve my code writing skills... (see some of my suggestions in a separate answer)

Comment: @Ryan Stewart I'm confused then.  I've found that the best comments are inline with the code to explain what the purpose of each major function call in a function body was supposed to do, or each step of a non-trivial algorithm was.  Furthermore, I've been praised in code reviews for the usefulness and conciseness of my comments.  When I said "comment like crazy" I mean make sure you have plenty of useful comments (not just comments for the sake of comments).  *Human-readable* code is art

Comment: @Brian: Your last statement says it all. The *code* should be readable. Comments get stale. Code never does. If you feel the need for comments, refactor until the code is so clear that comments would just be repeating what the code says. The only good comment is one that says why the code works a particular way--like to avoid a bug in a third party library--so that someone doesn't go back and change it to something that won't work for a reason that isn't immediately apparent.

Comment: I've officially been humbled.  Sorry @amaidment.  I guess need to research good coding standards when it comes to comments.

Answer (score 17):

A few brief points:

- [Intent-revealing](http://xunitpatterns.com/Intent%20Revealing%20Name.html) names
- [No non-instructive comments](http://mark-kirby.co.uk/2009/comments-are-evil/)
- No method with a complexity so high that you can't fit it all in your head at once
- [Single-responsibility objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
- Follow code conventions (you said you didn't care about it, but it's vitally important)

Comment: +1.  Perhaps most critical: minimize duplicated code.  If you are tempted to cut and paste more than a few tokens, you need to extract a function.  Even if the function is a single line of code.

Comment: On duplicated code, I take the following stance. Cut and paste = okay. That's just moving code (assuming you use paste once). Copy and paste = horrible. If you just remove the copy button from your vocabulary, you're more likely to do the right thing.

Comment: @jsternberg: +1 for cut/copy distinction, but I notice that a lot of people say "cut/paste" when they mean "copy/paste". I don't know how the distinction was lost.

Comment: Do not repeat yourself. Do not repeat yourself. Do not repeat yourself.

Comment: @configurator, you smell a little bit funny...

Comment: Steve McConnell, Code Complete.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Ryan's list:

- Follow the [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) principles
- Ensure that your code doesn't have too much [cyclic complexity](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html)
- [Test Driven](http://www.agilesherpa.org/agile_coach/engineering_practices/test_driven_development/) Java is always a good thing
- If you have a `xFactoryFactory` class, you're doing it wrong :-)
- Given the open source libraries in the Java ecosystem, re-inventing the wheel is bad style
- Use [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for date and time

I'll stop there.

Comment: But what about the `HammerFactoryFactoryFactory` class? ;-)

Comment: @Wayne, Factories are an indication that some decisions need to be delayed, and FactoryFactoryFactories indicate that there is a decision that really needed to be made at runtime but couldn't.

Comment: I know, I was being sarcastic and referencing that article about why then-J2EE was overly complex, with HammerFactories and HammerFactoryFactories and I think HammerFactoryFactoryFactories. :)

Comment: @Martijn - thanks for the SOLID link; I've not come across that before. You suggest using JodaTime; is this just an (appropriate) aversion to the Java Calendar/Date classes? What about JSR310 (the successor to JodaTime)?

Comment: JSR-310 will hopefully make it into Java 8 (there's a bunch of us gearing up to try and help make that happen, contact me if you want to get involved). In the mean time, Joda time is the defacto std for dealing with date and time in Java. There's so many things wrong with Java's Date and Calendar system that I don't even know where to start ;-). The killer is that Dates are mutable and that there's no concept of an instant or period or... nope I'm gonna stop there :-).

Comment: @Martin: any hope for fixing the hopeless mapping of java Date to SQL date, with its obscure implied timezone conversions?

Comment: JSR-310 should address that, but there's clearly some engineering effort required to make the new date and time classes operate smoothly with the older APIs (all part of Java's backwards compatible promise).

Comment: Just saw this old answer again - the good news is that JSR-310 is making it into Java 8, and developers rejoyced :-)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst appreciative of others' answers, I thought it only fair to share a few of the things I think about when trying to write good code:

- what needs to know about this class/method/variable? i.e. where should this knowledge live?
- how might this code affect the memory/performance of my application? (I acknowledge that 'premature optimisation is the root of all evil'; so I'm not suggesting spending lots of time optimising, but rather a consciousness whilst initially writing my code.)
- is it clear (from the code, and code structures) what this does? (I try to follow the maxim: "Strive not to make it possible for people to understand, strive to make it impossible for people to misunderstand".)

Answer (score 1):

Read the String and ArrayList class for excellent examples of proper Java programming. But they are highly concise, almost C style, which isn't necessarily best for maintainable code w/ minimal java docs. The common practice at my shop is no comments, so I try to comment by code by using verbose camelCase var names and excessive use of newlines to delimit one line of thought from another. I still debate using tabs to separate vars from their values. Tabs can enhance readability, IMO, but only when done minimally and it's very subjective. I find it's really about the audience. There's no best answer here.